# Sharepoint Designer 2013 "Could not save the list changes to the server"

Tags: asp.net, forms, sharepoint, edit, sharepoint-designer

This error comes up when trying to create a new list item edit form in sharepoint designer for me and my colleagues. I have deleted the WebCache and made sure that there are no references to columns that no longer exist, as other forums say to do, but the issue persists.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Could it be a permission issue?

Comment: I have site owner permissions and the person that created the site also can't create a form